# How to get the return value of __setitem__ call on python dict

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just extended the default behavior of **setitem** method of a dict to look like this

```
class SafeSwapDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(key, collections.Hashable):
            super(SafeSwapDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)
        else return False
    return True
```

When i'm calling that method i would like to get those return values but i cannot seem to find a turnaround since

```
a = SafeSwapDict()
print a['1'] =  132
```

won't work (it expects `=` to be `==`)

Also

```
a = SafeSwapDict()
w = a['1'] = 132
print w
```

will output 132 (it will first execute the right hand side of the statement (`a['1'] = 132`) and then copy the value into w, not the method's return value )

The following works, but it is not really useful (why overload an operator if you cannot use it as intended?)

```
print dict_out.__setitem__(1, 132)
```

Any other suggestions?
P.S. I'm not allowed to use exception handling :)

Comment: so i cannot test if my method call succeeded or not ? (i can still get what i want by adding another attribute `'success_assign'` which will be set to True when entering the function and to False if it didn't succeeded)

Comment: @NiCU If it didn't succeed, it should throw an exception which you can handle.

Comment: @glglgl I know, but I'm constrained not to use exceptions.

Comment: @NiCU O-kay. That is strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific example, `dict` returns `False` only if your key is not Hashable. In any other case, the assignement works.

Just like when you make any assignement `some_var = 2`, you don't need to test if `some_var` really is `2`, because it is.

In the case of `dict`, an invalid key (such as a `list`) will fail and you'll be notified:

```
>>> some_dict = {}
>>> some_dict[[0]] = 42   #the key is a list [0], unhashable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

In summary, you don't need to test the success of your assignement, because it never silently fails.

Comment: I know it's supposed to raise an exception if the key is not hashable but I'm constrained not to use exception handling for this task :|